# Boolean Function Always Return False

Tags: c++, function, return, boolean

It must be true but function returns false. I can't understand. How it is possible?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool Testing() {
    static int Variable = 0;

    if (Variable == 1) return true;
    else {
        Variable = 1;
        Testing();
    }

    return false;
}

int main()
{
    if (Testing()) cout << "True";
    else cout << "False";
}
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps it should be `return Testing();`. It is also a good idea to mark function with `[[nodiscard]]` attribute to avoid such typos in the future.

Comment: Are you doing a recursion in ```Testing()```?

Comment: This seems to be a common newbie misunderstanding. If the function calls itself, `return` from a nested call only returns up one level (rather than directly to `main`). So after you `return true`, control returns to the first `Testing` call, then continues until you hit `return false`, then returns to `main`.

Comment: Yes, it is. I'm trying something.

Comment: Consider how the code in `Testing` is already following a path to return false at the time that it recursively calls `Testing` and in your code, nothing is changing the fact that it's on track to return false.

Comment: I didn't understand. Can you explain this otherwise? @HolyBlackCat

Comment: How did you determine that `Testing` always returns `false`? You're showing it about to return `true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `main()` calls `Testing()` for the 1st time, the `static` variable is created and initialized to 0.  So the `if` evaluates to `false`, the variable gets updated to 1, and `Testing()` is called a 2nd time.  And like any other function, that call will return to the place where it was called from.

Inside the 2nd `Testing()` run, the `static` initialization is skipped, and since the variable is already 1, the `if` evaluates as `true`, and so `true` gets returned to the caller, which is in the 1st run.

But, regardless of what that 2nd run does internally, the call site inside of the 1st run is ignoring the `bool` value that is returned, and so flow continues on normally, reaching the `return false;` statement, returning `false` back to the call site of the 1st run, which is in `main()`.

```cpp
bool Testing() {
    static int Variable = 0;

    if (Variable == 1)
        return true; // <-- 2nd run reaches here
    else {
                     // <-- 1st run reaches here
        Variable = 1;
        Testing();   // <-- 2nd function call made here
                     // <-- returns to here, but value is being ignored, so...
    }

    return false; // <-- 1st run reaches here, returns to main
}
```

To fix this, inside of `Testing()`, you need to change this line:

```cpp
Testing();
```

To this instead:

```cpp
return Testing();
```

That way, when the 2nd run returns `true`, the 1st run will also return `true.`  main()`will receive the final`true`that the last recursive call to`Testing()` returns.

Comment: Thank you very much but I don't fully understand this part: No matter what happens after that, you are ignoring the bool that the recursive Testing() call returns, and then you return false back to main().